# Get the value of a input number in jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, numbers

I'm working on a form, and I want to get in real time the current value of an input field of type number, as this one :

```js
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
  var coins = $("#coins").val();
  $("#reward").text(coins);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="coins" type="number" name="coins" value="1" max="999" min="1">

<p id="potential">Potential reward : <b id="reward"></b></p>
```

But nothing happen when I run it. It says that the value of coins is null. I don't know what I am doing wrong...
Anyone could help ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
$(document).on('input', '#coin', function(){
    var coins = $("#coins").val();
    $("#reward").text(coins);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Code shown works fine when user makes edits.

If you need it to display when page loads just trigger one of the events

```js
$(":input").on('keyup mouseup', function () {
  var coins = $("#coins").val();
  $("#reward").text(coins);
}).trigger('mouseup');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="coins" type="number" name="coins" value="1" max="999" min="1">

<p id="potential">Potential reward : <b id="reward"></b></p>
```

Note that `bind()` is deprecated in favor of using `on()`

Comment: I saw that the snippet is working well... I don't understand why my code is not working on my own, surely problems with something else.
I will try to search again. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: We can't help fix it without a way to reproduce the problem

Comment: I finally found my error :) It was just an issue of id that was already used :)